# Firebase, Google Auth, limit registration to a specific domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I use google authentication in my application. I would like to give the option of registering and logging in to the application only to people from a specific organization, with a specific domain in the email. Is it possible for Firebase to reject a Google login attempt from a different domain than @mydomain.pl?

I used Bard and executed the instruction by entering these commands into the console

```
firebase projects add-to-config DOMAIN_NAME firebase.auth.allowedDomains
```

Unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `firebase blocking functions` to only allow people from a specific organization to create an account or sign in to your application.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Will run before a user is created
exports.beforeCreate = functions.auth.user().beforeCreate((user, context) => {

     // Checks if the email does not belong to the organization
     if(!user?.email?.includes("@yourorganization.com")){
        throw new Error("permission-denied","You are not part of our organization")
    }
    });
```

Check out the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions?gen=1st) for further information.